# Django MultiChoiceField with extra field

Tags: python, django, forms, multichoiceitems

Basically I need to create a multichoicefield, witch additionally has quantity field.

So for each choice I need to add this extra positiveinteger field but i don't know how to add it.

EDIT:

I need to make orders, so you need to check what elements you want to add to the order, and how many of each you want.

Comment: could you clarify what are you trying to do? Perhaps an example?

Comment: I need to make orders, so you need to check what elements you want to add to the order, and how many of each you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need two different fields. First one, with the element, and another one with the quantity. Then, when you recover them (from a form normally) you can handle them as you want (in the view), and you could store them in the db (by model).

Could be:

```
class Order(forms.Form):
  quantity = forms.IntegerField()
  product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.values("name").distinct())
  client = forms.CharField()
```

By the other hand, if you want to add several products and quantities, you could use two buttons, Add and Order.
Add, will go storing each name_of_product and quantity in a dictionary which will be a session variable.
Order, will recover this dictionary and will do your stuff (sending a email, storing in db, and so on...)